# How can I add custom HTML & Javascript tags in AMP Container through Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager, amp-html

I'm implementing AMP in my website. I would like to call all the external scripts through Google Tag Manager Custom HTML tags. Unfortunately it's available only in Web version of container and not in AMP version of container. How can I add custom HTML & Javascript tags in AMP Container through Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom HTML Tags are unavailable in GTM AMP Containers by design. From [AMPs documentation](http://ampready.com/getting-started):

> script tags are prohibited except the mandatory script tag to load the
>   AMP runtime and the script tags to load extended components. Non
>   executable script tags such as ld+json tags are allowed.

Comment: if so, how to add facebook pixel? thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If there is no template available it cannot be implemented atm.
The essence of AMP is that google prohibits you to use custom javascript which can possibly slow down pages.

Only 3rd party tags which have a template in GTM can be used.
Watch out , there are several 3rd party tags that ARE allowed hardcoded in your amp-page but have no GTM template, example = Gemius tags.

You are very limited atm in using GA/GTM on AMP Pages.